# RegEx Word Boundary

Tags: php, regex

I'm experimenting with PHP and building a search function, as a test to myself.

I am struggling on regular expressions. My code is below:

```
$submission = $_GET['Search'];
function scanLines($lines, $submission) {
    foreach($lines as $line) {      
        if(strpos($line,$submission)!== false){         
            preg_match_all("/\b".$submission."\b/", $line, $matches);

            var_dump($matches);
        }           
    }       
}
```

I have a text file, each having a small sentence per line. For example, if the line to search is:

'I have a camera'

I submit 'cam' into my search, I want it to return the word camera.

It seems the word boundary at the end does not work, and cannot grab the end of the string.

Any takers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [preg_quote](https://www.php.net/preg_quote) over the `$submission`. And remove the boundary at the end, and make `[a-z]+` or `[a-z]*` to pick rest of it after.

```
preg_match_all("/\b[a-z]*".preg_quote($submission)."[a-z]*\b/i", $line, $matches);
```

`i` for case insensitive.

Comment: This works good, if I use the characters in the beginning. If I use 'ame' in the middle of 'camera', it does not return anything. . I am trying to understand this a bit better. So the boundary is detected in the beginning, and a wildcard after for any letter till the end of the word?

Comment: @JustinBevan that case you can use `[a-z]*` right after the `\b`. Which means `\b[a-z]*`

Comment: This works well. So this is essentially using a wildcard for characters before, till word boundary. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you can do this for the right side of the text as well. Like `[a-z]*\b`.

Comment: `[a-z]` means any character from `a` to `z` and `*` means having them zero or more times. If you use `[a-f]` it will mean any characters from `a` to `f`

Comment: This would fail if user searches for `amera`.

Comment: So true, it won't find `stackoverflow` if search string is `over` OR `flow`

Comment: Hi @AmalMurali thanks. i mentioned that on my earlier comments. I have updated the answer. Is it ok now?

Answer (score 3):

If your line is: `I have a camera` and you are trying to match on `cam` then of course you cannot use `\b` on both sides of search string.

Besides that you should also use `preg_quote` to make matches using special regex symbols.

Probably this should work better for you:

```
preg_match("/" . preg_quote($submission) . "/", $line, $matches);
```

**EDIT:** Based on comments, you can do:

```
function scanLines($lines, $submission) {
   found=array();
   foreach($lines as $line) {      
      // if ( preg_match_all('/\S*' . preg_quote($submission) . '\S*/', $line, $m) ) OR
      if ( preg_match_all('/\w*' . preg_quote($submission) . '\w*/', $line, $m) )
         $found[] = $m[0];
   }
   return $found;
}
```

Comment: This only returns the string passed through the $_GET from my input field. It does not return the rest after. This example should essentially return the word, regardless of what is before/after.

Comment: You mean you want to return the whole line if match is successful?

Comment: If I search 'cam' in a sentence "John has a camera in his hand", I simply want this to return 'Camera' or any term containing the string I submit, which would utilize preg_match_all.

Comment: I think this is a better solution. You don't really need `preg_match_all()` here, @Justin.

Comment: For this case I do, it is going to search all instances. I wanted this to be scalable for any paragraph, sentence, etc.

Comment: And why do you think this answer is not scalable?

Comment: preg_match returns the first and only the first match.
preg_match_all returns an array with all of the matches.

Comment: Very true and I know that very well. You can use `preg_match_all` also here, but regex has to be correct that is first thing.

Comment: Yes, the [a-z]* was the missing piece here. Your help was greatly appreciated, however. :)

Comment: You are probably not understanding the regex difference here. Read my comment on other answer.